# useRouter - query object is empty

Tags: next.js, next-router

i'm trying to learn routing in Next.JS but I can't manage to get the query object.

File path: `./src/pages/[test]/index.tsx`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function Test() {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(router.query);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`console.log` just prints `{}`

Comment: `query` there refers to the query string in the url. E.g. `/yourTest?query=Hello`. Do I misunderstand something or you forget to provide more information into this?

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes
According to documentation query referrs to params like http://localhost:3000/Hello (router.query should've print { test: 'Hello' })

Comment: That is correct, however it will be an empty object during prerendering if the page doesn't have [data fetching requirement](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching). Might this be the case?

Comment: It was it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your page is a [dynamic route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes), and you expect `query` to have route parameters in it, It is **expected** to have it empty during pre-rendering phase if your page is statically optimized by [Automatic Static Optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization).

Quoting from [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats)

> Pages that are statically optimized by Automatic Static Optimization
> will be hydrated without their route parameters provided, i.e query
> will be an empty object ({}).
>
> After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to
> provide the route parameters in the query object.

It is possible to watch the `query` in `useEffect` like following;

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(router.query);
}, [router.query]);
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same and the page is not a dynamic route though it does have some children from it. For example page is on /shop and there is also shop/checkout and shop/products but I am targeting shop/index

Comment: Never mind, simply the fact that it has query parameters in the URL is another qualifier for it